# Should I change mysql.connect_timeout variable in php.ini?

Tags: drupal, upgrade, mysql

MySQL has been losing connection on me while trying to complete the upgrade. I am wondering if I should change the php.ini variable `mysql.connect_timeout = 60` to a value of `-1` (unlimited) and if this will help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have definitely altered this variable for upgrades, but my notes show I only increased the values to `1800`.

I don't recall whether this was because I found that `-1` didn't work, or because I preferred to not allow a connection to remain open indefinitely.

So yes, I think you should alter it if necessary to complete upgrade.

If you find setting to `-1` works, make sure to change it back post-upgrade!